# writing the contents of a list to a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv, export-to-csv

I'm writing the contents of list to a csv file using the code below.

```
    import csv

    text_file = open("memberstest.txt", "r")
    lines = text_file.read().split(' ')
    print(lines)


    myfile = open('members.csv','w')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=" ")
    wr.writerows(lines)
    myfile.close()
```

The problem I'm having is that each word is written to a new row rather than keeping each record on a separate row. For instance my list looks like this:

```
["['user1',", "'01/01/01',", "'blue',", "'green'['user2',", "'12/12/12',", "'pink',", "'orange']['user3',", "'03/03/03',", "'purple',", "'green']"]
```

When I execute my code my csv file looks like:

```
[ ' u s e r 1 ' 

' 0 1 / 0 1 / 0 1 ' 

' b l u e ' 

' g r e e n ' ] [ ' u s e r 2 ' 

' 1 2 / 1 2 / 1 2 ' 

' p i n k ' 

' o r a n g e ' ] [ ' u s e r 3 ' 

' 0 3 / 0 3 / 0 3 ' 

' p u r p l e ' 

' g r e e n ' ]
```

It leaves a line gap after each word and the last item and first item in each record it joins together.

What I would like to see is:

```
user 1   01/01/01   blue  green
user 2   12/12/12   pink   orange
```

etc.

I have tried different options for the delimiter and even tried it without but I'm not having much success. Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's because the list that you've provided (or rather, the list that's in your file) _is_ the list that the csv file is writing out. Try testing `lines[0]` or `lines[3]` to see how the list looks after you read it.

Comment: nope sorry, does not have the desired effect. Not only is it printing as shown above but the last word in a record and the first word in the next record always appear joined.

Comment: That's what I'm saying - your input list is already messed up so it would take a great deal of effort to correct it in your script. Try to fix the file that is reading in the list, and your script should function as you expect.
For context, it would be helpful if you also gave us what's in `memberstest.txt`.

Comment: Okay thanks for the response. I have been working on this since I originally posted so I would like to provide how far I have got with correcting the problem. I will first start by stating how I am writing to memberstest.txt. Then I will show the contents of the file. This file is then edited with a new password for a user and written back to the text file as when I try writing to a csv file it for some strange reason leaves of the final item (which is either admin or access). I will do this by adding to "answer your question". I am mostly there now which is infuriating as I'm so close.

Answer (score 0):

I first write a new user to a text file:

```
import time
import csv

    account = input("Do you want to create an OCRtunes account? Y/N  ")
    if account == "Y" or account == "y":

        adduser = []
        user = str(input("enter user: "))
        adduser.append(user.strip())
        print("----------------------------------------------")
        username = input("enter your username: ")
        adduser.append(username.strip())
        print("-----------------------------------------------")
        password = input("enter password: ")
        adduser.append(password.strip())
        print("------------------------------------------------")
        rights = input("enter admin or client: ")
        adduser.append(rights.strip() + "\n")
        print(adduser)
        -------------------")
        reply = input("Do you want these details to be saved? ")

        if reply =="Y" or reply =="y":

            with open('memberstestv2.txt', 'a') as f:
                str(adduser)
                f.writelines(",".join(adduser))
                print (adduser)
                f.close()

            print("User created")
```

The details in the memberstest2.txt file are saved like:

```
user1,username1,password1,admin
user2,username2,password2,access
user3,username3,password3,access
```

Then when I want to edit the password for a user and write back to the same file or a new csv file I do:

```
with open('memberstestv2.txt') as fo:
    user = []
    updated_list = []

    for rec in fo:
        user.append(rec.split(','))

    print(user)
    username=input("Enter username: ")

    for row in user:
        for field in row:
            if username == field:
                updated_list.append(row)
                print("user found")
                password = input("enter new password: ")
                updated_list[0][2] = password
                print(updated_list)

                for index, row in enumerate(user):
                    for field in row:
                        if field == updated_list[0]:
                            user[index] = updated_list # Replace old record with updated record.


                with open("memberstestv2.txt","w", newline='') as f:
                    Writer=csv.writer(f)
                    Writer.writerows(user)
                    print("password has been updated")

                exit
```

In the console this is what the output look likes:

```
[['user1', 'username1', 'password1', 'admin\n'], ['user2', 'username2', 'password2', 'access\n'], ['user3', 'username3', 'password3', 'access']]
Enter username: user1
user found
enter new password: new password
[['user1', 'username1', 'new password', 'admin\n']]
password has been updated
```

However, in the text file the data is saved with quotation marks around the last item like:

```
user1,username1,new password,"admin
"
user2,username2,password2,"access
"
user3,username3,password3,access
```

If I proceed to update another password the result in the console is:

```
[['user1', 'username1', 'new password', '"admin\n'], ['"\n'], ['user2', 'username2', 'password2', '"access\n'], ['"\n'], ['user3', 'username3', 'password3', 'access\n']]
Enter username: user2
user found
enter new password: new password 2
[['user2', 'username2', 'new password 2', '"access\n']]
password has been updated
```

In the text file it is saved as:

```
user1,username1,new password,"""admin
"
"""
"
user2,username2,new password 2,"""access
"
"""
"
user3,username3,password3,"access
"
```

It seems to add quotations each time I update a password. If I try writing to a csv file it works but does not write the final column.

Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks